# Can we perforn a permutation test with zero-inflated data?

Tags: zero-inflation, permutation-test

In a collaborative problem-solving task, I would like to check if the mean number of communicative exchanges emitted by a person is different following whether they shared an emotion just before or not.

Communicative exchanges are divided into windows of 5 exchanges. For a same person, there are 1 to 5 windows with emotion sharing and 30 to 40 windows with no-emotion sharing. I computed the number of communicative exchanges for a specific category of exchange and I divided this number by the number of windows for both emotion sharing and no-emotion sharing.

Some categories of communicative exchanges are very rare (for example 100 exchanges out of 5000 exchanges in total).

Therefore, this kind of data occurred (see below). In this example, p-value is significant. Is it valid to compute a permutation test in this condition, with zero-inflated data? The two conditions are also paired.

```
       Emotion sharing        No-Emotion Sharing
D02P01        0                        0
D05P01        0                        0
D07P01        0                        0.03125
D13P01        0                        0
D16P01        0                        0
D09P01        0                        0
D21P01        0                        0
D23P01        0                        0.1111111
D26P01        0                        0 
D27P01        0                        0.03030303   
D29P01        0                        0.01470588
D02P02        0                        0
D07P02        0                        0.05769231
D09P02        0                        0
D13P02        0                        0
D16P02        0                        0
D21P02        0                        0
D23P02        0                        0.03448276   
D26P02        0                        0.03125
D27P02        0                        0
```

Comment: i couldn't really follow your question, but in general there should not be a problem with zero inflated data and a permutation test, just be sure you take your dependencies (subjects, windows) into an account and shuffle only within exchangeable blocks